# Insert jsonb object to other jsonb by key

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have the following data defined as jsonb.

```
{
   "rules":[
      {
         "group":"identifier",
         "logic":"=",
         "value":"token",
         "fieldId":"vfde_0010"
      },
      {
         "rules":[
            {
               "group":"identifier",
               "logic":"=",
               "value":"111",
               "fieldId":"vfde_0011"
            }
         ],
         "condition":"and"
      }
   ],
   "version":"v_0021",
   "category":"mobile",
   "condition":"and",
   "createdAt":"2020-01-17T03:13:42Z"
}
```

Then i want to include this new jsonb data to the above.

```
{
   "rules":[
      {
         "group":"identifier",
         "logic":"=",
         "value":"msisdn-sha2",
         "fieldId":"vfde_0010"
      }
   ],
   "condition":"and"
}
```

So the result would be.

```
{
   "rules":[
      {
         "group":"identifier",
         "logic":"=",
         "value":"token",
         "fieldId":"vfde_0010"
      },
      {
         "rules":[
            {
               "group":"identifier",
               "logic":"=",
               "value":"111",
               "fieldId":"vfde_0011"
            }
         ],
         "condition":"and"
      },
      {
         "rules":[
            {
               "group":"identifier",
               "logic":"=",
               "value":"msisdn-sha2",
               "fieldId":"vfde_0010"
            }
         ],
         "condition":"and"
      }
   ],
   "version":"v_0021",
   "category":"mobile",
   "condition":"and",
   "createdAt":"2020-01-17T03:13:42Z"
}
```

I try to use || operator but i confused with the result: (data->>'rules' || new).

```
[
   {
      "group":"identifier",
      "logic":"=",
      "value":"token",
      "fieldId":"vfde_0010"
   },
   {
      "rules":[
         {
            "group":"identifier",
            "logic":"=",
            "value":"111",
            "fieldId":"vfde_0011"
         }
      ],
      "condition":"and"
   }
]{
   "rules":[
      {
         "group":"identifier",
         "logic":"=",
         "value":"msisdn-sha2",
         "fieldId":"vfde_0010"
      }
   ],
   "condition":"and"
}
```

Do i use the wrong operator or is there another right way to do this?

I use PostgreSQL 12.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `jsonb_insert`.

Try:

```
jsonb_insert(data, '{ rules, 2 }', (your new value))
```

Also see the [jsonb documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://www.enterprisedb.com)

Comment: Thanks, i want to accept your answer, but i must wait 4 minutes. Working query: ```jsonb_insert(data, '{rules,0}', new)```